# Symfony 4, findAll with entity's property as array key

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4

From symfony 4, when I use the method findAll I get an associative array of my entity's objects, where each key is one an object of my entity

I am looking for a pretty way to get instead an associative array where the key is the value of a specific field of my entity, and the value the object of my entity.

In practical terms, when I use findAll I get this :

```
Array
(
    [0] => App\Entity\Foo Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Foo:private] => 1
            [name:App\Entity\Foo:private] => nameValue1
        )

    [1] => App\Entity\Foo Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Foo:private] => 2
            [name:App\Entity\Foo:private] => nameValue2
        )

    [2] => App\Entity\Foo Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Foo:private] => 3
            [name:App\Entity\Foo:private] => nameValue3
        )
        ...
)
```

But, instead, I want this :

```
Array
(
    ["nameValue1"] => App\Entity\Foo Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Foo:private] => 1
            [name:App\Entity\Foo:private] => nameValue1
        )

    ["nameValue2"] => App\Entity\Foo Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Foo:private] => 2
            [name:App\Entity\Foo:private] => nameValue2
        )

    ["nameValue3"] => App\Entity\Foo Object
        (
            [id:App\Entity\Foo:private] => 3
            [name:App\Entity\Foo:private] => nameValue3
        )
        ...
)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To get this functionality you have to implement your own function in the repository of `Foo` class and use QueryBuilder's `indexBy()`  :

```
<?php

namespace App\Repository;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

class FooRepository extends EntityRepository
{

    public function findAllIndexed()
    {
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('foo');
        $query = $qb->indexBy('foo', 'foo.name')->getQuery();
        return $query->getResult();
    }
}
```

Now you just call `$repository->findAllIndexed()` instead of `$repository->findAll()` function.

Comment: This seems perfect ! thank you :) however , I get a Notice warning when I call the findAllIndexed, the notice is "Notice: Undefined offset: 1", is it problematic ?

Comment: This doesn't seem to be relation with findAllIndexed function. Please use dump($query->getResult()); before the return statement inside findAllIndexed() so that you can see exactly what this function returns.

Comment: This notice were from another location of my code, that was my bad !